# How is tunnel ID generated w/ VS Code ports / devtunnels.ms

Tags: visual-studio-code, dev-tunnels

When using the "Ports" feature of VS Code to forward a local service to a public URL via a tunnel, the resulting URL is something like:

`https://{tunnel-id}-{port}.use.devtunnels.ms`

How is the `{tunnel-id}` portion of this URL generated? I've observed that when stopping and re-running this port forwarding, including on different ports and even from different local VS Code projects, that ID has always been a consistent value for me.

Is the tunnel ID derived somehow from my GitHub account? My particular computer? I can't find any documentation elaborating on where the ID comes from.

I write developer training material, and before I recommend this feature as a way to create a tunnel to a local service, I want to know whether I can tell devs in what circumstances they can rely on a consistent URL.